# How to write a CSP with wildcard?

Tags: content-security-policy

I am writing a CSP for my website, the header is added via Lambda@Edge on AWS for my site on lightsail. I've got the CSP set as follows, been trying to get it to work: `content-security-policy: default-src 'self' *.thetechcapsule.com thetechcapsule.com; img-src 'self'; script-src 'self'; style-src 'self'; object-src 'none'`

My domain is thetechcapsule.com and I have cloudfront CDN set up via [www.thetechcapsule.com](http://www.thetechcapsule.com). I thought the wildcard would allow all subdomains but it's not working, getting script errors, but they should be using the default source?

E.g of error in console

```
Refused to load the script '<URL>' because it violates the following Content Security Policy directive: "script-src 'self'". Note that 'script-src-elem' was not explicitly set, so 'script-src' is used as a fallback.
```

Thanks

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Instead of `'self'` the browser substitutes exact tuple: scheme+hostname+port with which page was loaded.

If you load page from Url `http://example.com`, the `'self'` will be `http://example.com` and it does nol allow `http://www.example.com`.

If page is loaded as `https://www.example.com`, `'self'` became `https://www.example.com` and it will not allow `https://example.com` or `http://www.example.com` (schemes are differs in last case).

Therefore, if your page loads resourses both from `site.com` and `www.site.com`, you need to do in the `script-src` directive exactly what you did in the `default-src`:

```
script-src 'self' *.thetechcapsule.com thetechcapsule.com;
```

May be the same will required for styles/images if you mix `site.com` and `www.site.com` for resource loading.

Note: In the CSP3-compatible browsers, the 'self' token additionally covers the `ws:` and `wss:` schemes. And `http://example.com` allows to be upgraded to `https://example.com`.